# How to get the submitted value of a form in a Django class-based view?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django form that looks like this:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label="Email",
        max_length=254,
        required=True,
    )
```

I have a an associated Class-Based FormView as shown below. I can see that the form is succesfully validating the data and flow is getting into the form_valid() method below. What I need to know is how to get the value that the user submitted in the email field. `form.fields['email'].value` doesn't work.

```
class myFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'myTemplate.html'
    form_class = myForm
    success_url = "/blahblahblah"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        # How Do I get the submitted values of the form fields here?
        # I would like to do a log.debug() of the email address?
        return super(myFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check the form's `cleaned_data` attribute, which will be a dictionary with your fields as keys and values as values. Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data).

Example:

```
class myFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'myTemplate.html'
    form_class = myForm
    success_url = "/blahblahblah"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']  # <--- Add this line to get email value
        return super(myFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: what if the form contains a many to many field? How do you retrieve all values submitted in class based views?

Comment: My model generated a randomly generated slug. I need to retrieve this slug so the user can see the URL to the item created via an Email. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
 form.cleaned_data.get('email')
```